# Jumping to a specific line in python file operations

Tags: python, file, loops, for-loop

I have a list,

```
brands= [["mercedes"], ["bmw"], ["ferrari"]]
```

a file named `brands.txt`

```
mercedes: a, b, c, g , x , y
bmw: d, e, g, a, b, g, x 
ferrari: x, y, z, a, b, c
```

and eventually another list

```
variables = ["b", "c", "a", "y", "x", "z"]
```

What I'm trying to do is to pick a brand in the 1st list and find its variables according to the file, which is sorted of highly preference of customers and this is the code I have written so far

```
 with open("brands.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line=line.replace("\n","").split(",")[1:]
        print(line)
        for i in line:
           for a in brands:
               for j in a:
                   for k in j:
                       if k in i:
                           line=line.split(",")[1:]
                           print line
```

The expected output when the brand `mercedes` is chosen will be like

```
["a", "b", "c", "x", "y"]
```

according to highly preference, but 
my code does not work... Can you help me about it?

Comment: What are you doing with all the nested loops?

Comment: trying to reach the main brand.. it look so bad .. i know

Comment: I don't quite get *sorted of highly preference of customers*, can you explain what output you expect and why?

Comment: mercedes: a,b,c.. vs are listed as preference of customer.. likewise "a" is the most popular element and c is the least..
according the that knowledge that  are given i must sort variables from most popular and least popular

Comment: what have the variables got to do with the problem?

Comment: they are chosen randomly from another file ..and i must sort them according to the mercedes line in which a is the most popular and c is the least.

Comment: So you have to sort variable based on its index?

Comment: yes thats what i'm trying to do

Comment: what about `g` and other letters that are not in the line?

Comment: just the intersection will be listed in order..

Comment: So `['b', 'c', 'a', 'y', 'x', 'g']` is valid then?

Comment: yes it is valid but there is another question for you.. what if i want to code it again for all of the elements of brands list.. which way i must follow?

Comment: I edited the answer, you just need to iterate over the dict and sort each list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand how you want to **choose** (as you put it) a variable, so I used dictionaries to keep your text data.

Try it like this

```
customers = {}
for line in f:
    line_key = line.split(" ")[0][:-1]
    line_values = map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split(":")[1].split(","))
    customers[line_key] = line_values
```

then call a key

```
print customers["mercedes"]
```

Which gives you

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'x', 'y']
```

I have to point out if the text data corrupted and do not match with the car names in your Python file, your dictionary call will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with any letter that is not in the line but you can use a dict to map index to letter and use that as the key to sort with:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    variables = ["b", "c", "a", "y", "x", "z"]

    key = dict(zip(variables, range(len(variables))))

    d = dict((k, list(map(str.strip, v.split(",")))) for line in f for k, v in (line.strip().split(":"),))

    for k, v in d.items():
        v.sort(key=lambda x: key.get(x, float("inf")))
        print("Key = {}\nSorted values = {}\n".format(k,v))
```

Output:

```
Key = bmw
Sorted values = ['b', 'a', 'x', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'g']

Key = ferrari
Sorted values = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'y', 'x', 'z']

Key = mercedes
Sorted values = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'y', 'x', 'g']
```

All the values in your dict will be in sorted order, using `float("inf")` as the default value will mean the keys not in the dict will be sorted at the end of the list.